# Добавить в запрос поиск по связанной таблице

Tags: android, sqlite, room

Есть две таблицы `Order` и `Customer`. В таблице `Order` есть поле `idCustomer`. В  таблице `Customer` есть поле `Name`.
Есть запрос который ищет по полям в таблице `Order` все совпадения

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `Order` WHERE dateCreate LIKE '%'||:query||'%' OR number LIKE '%'||:query||'%'" +
        " OR description LIKE '%'||:query||'%' OR address LIKE '%'||:query||'%' OR phone LIKE '%'||:query||'%'")
LiveData<List<Order>> getAllSearch(String query);
```

Вопрос, что нужно в этот запрос добавить, чтобы искало еще и по таблице `Customer`, а именно по полю `Name`?

Comment: Я бы использовал left join

Comment: @Circassian спасибо, ищет, правда ругается на одинаковое название полей в двух таблицах

Comment: Таблице можно задать псевдоним и обращаться к полям через точку

Comment: Должно получиться что-то типа этого https://ibb.co/SVJ25M3

Comment: @Circassian а нельзя присоединить только одно поле name из таблицы Customer, мне только оно и нужно?

Comment: Вот ответ и на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219385/how-to-join-only-one-column

Comment: спасибо, проблему не решило, все равно ругается, просто не хочу переименовывать поля в таблице Order,желательно переименовать в таблице Customer

Answer (score 0):

В итоге с помощью ответов @Circassian пришел к такому рабочему варианту. Так как некоторые название полей в таблицах совпадали, переименовал их в таблице Customer.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Order`
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id AS idCust,
          name,
          phone AS phoneCust,
          description AS des
   FROM Customer) ON `Order`.idCustomer = idCust
WHERE number LIKE '%'||:query||'%'
  OR description LIKE '%'||:query||'%'
  OR address LIKE '%'||:query||'%'
  OR phone LIKE '%'||:query||'%'
  OR name LIKE '%'||:query||'%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```